# How to I prevent WordPress from switching external HTTP links to HTTPS?

Tags: hooks, links

The website has an SSL certificate and uses https://, but when I link to a website using a text link pointing to http://domain.com and then preview it the link is updated to https://domain.com.

What causes this and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: WP Core doesn't do that by default - it's most likely a plugin you're using to enforce HTTPS on your own site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect a bad plugin, but you didn't provide enough information. But it could be a directive in your htaccess file that is not correct.

Take a look at this question/answer for a comprehensive discussion about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite .

If that doesn't help, provide more information about plugins and your htaccess file contents.

Comment: They were using a plugin that stripped the HTTP: and HTTPS: from the page in order to make every source secure. This plugin also changed all the links within the content area. Thanks for taking the time to comment. I should have looked at that first!